# How does OpenDayLight discover the network?

Tags: opendaylight

When I used the ONOS Controller, which uses the OpenFlow Discovery Protocol,
each switch had send a PacketIN encapsulated LLDP message back to the controller. These PacketINs are answering the LLDP messages the controller has send to discover the network. This was checked using wireshark.
I wanted to check if OpenDayLight had the same behaviour,
but there were no PacketINs.

Thats why I wanted to know how ODL gets topology information without receiving any LLDP packages  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing these three features:

```
odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest
odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer
odl-openflowplugin-app-topology-lldp-discovery
odl-openflowplugin-app-lldp-speaker
```

The first should give you basic openflow functionality and restconf with ODL.
The second should program each switch to punt packets to the controller by
default. The third should help discover the topology via lldp packets, and the
last should periodically pump lldp packets out of each switches ports.

Before (you asked this question), l2switch did this I guess, but that is a
dead project now. l2switch also did a little extra simulating spanning tree
in order to remove loops from the network and allowing hosts to ping each
other in the network. The above openflow features won't do that final part.
you can program your own flows though.

Comment: first of all thx. I've already activated these applications. What I see is that opendaylight periodically sends out ofpt_packet_out encapsulated lldp messages and  ofpt_multipart_request messages. But ryu and onos send  ofpt_packet_out messages as well and both are getting **ofpt_packet_in** encapsulated lldp messages back. odl doesn't get anything back from what I see.

Comment: can you check the switch's flows to see if there is a rule to punt these packets to the controller? I *thought* that is what you would get with the table-miss-enforcer feature.

Comment: Yeah, i checked again.
Now I am getting packet in messages.
So odl's behaviour is actually just like onos.